# How to get selected file path from GoogleDrive in Android integration?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have successfully integrated GoogleDrive in my Android application and now i can upload any file to drive from app. But i want to download file from drive to device for this i am using some code given below -

```
import java.net.URI;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityBuilder;

/**
 * An activity to illustrate how to pick a file with the opener intent.
 */
public class PickFileWithOpenerActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

 private static final String TAG = "PickFileWithOpenerActivity";

 private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 1;

 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
  super.onConnected(connectionHint);
  IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
    .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
    .setMimeType(
      new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html",
        "application/pdf", "audio/mp3", "video/mp4",
        "text/plain", "application/msword",
        "image/jpeg", "image/png", "text/html" })
    .build(getGoogleApiClient());
  try {
   startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null,
     0, 0, 0);
  } catch (SendIntentException e) {
   Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
  }

 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
  case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data
      .getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
    showMessage("Selected file's ID: " + driveId);

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    try {
     Log.d(TAG, "Drive Id=============== "
       + uri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FILE_ID = driveId.toString();

   }

   finish();
   break;
  default:
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
 }
}
```

Here is BaseDemoActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;

/**
 * An abstract activity that handles authorization and connection to the Drive
 * services.
 */
public abstract class BaseDemoActivity extends Activity implements
  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

 private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";

 /**
  * DriveId of an existing folder to be used as a parent folder in folder
  * operations samples.
  */
 public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "0B2EEtIjPUdX6MERsWlYxN3J6RU0";

 /**
  * DriveId of an existing file to be used in file operation samples..
  */
 public static String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "0ByfSjdPVs9MZTHBmMVdSeWxaNTg";

 /**
  * Extra for account name.
  */
 protected static final String EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name";

 /**
  * Request code for auto Google Play Services error resolution.
  */
 protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;

 /**
  * Next available request code.
  */
 protected static final int NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

 /**
  * Google API client.
  */
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

 /**
  * Called when activity gets visible. A connection to Drive services need to
  * be initiated as soon as the activity is visible. Registers
  * {@code ConnectionCallbacks} and {@code OnConnectionFailedListener} on the
  * activities itself.
  */
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
     .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
     .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
     // required for App Folder sample
     .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
     .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
  }
  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
 }

 /**
  * Handles resolution callbacks.
  */
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
  }
 }

 /**
  * Called when activity gets invisible. Connection to Drive service needs to
  * be disconnected as soon as an activity is invisible.
  */
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
   mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
  }
  super.onPause();
 }

 /**
  * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
  */
 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
  Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
 }

 /**
  * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is disconnected.
  */
 @Override
 public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
  Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
 }

 /**
  * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is trying to connect but failed.
  * Handle {@code result.getResolution()} if there is a resolution is
  * available.
  */
 @Override
 public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
  Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
  if (!result.hasResolution()) {
   // show the localized error dialog.
   GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
     0).show();
   return;
  }
  try {
   result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
  } catch (SendIntentException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
  }
 }

 /**
  * Shows a toast message.
  */
 public void showMessage(String message) {
  Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 /**
  * Getter for the {@code GoogleApiClient}.
  */
 public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
  return mGoogleApiClient;
 }
}
```

I want to get file path in PickFileWithOpenerActivity currently i am getting selected file id using DriveId in onActivityResult Please someone help me and tell me how i can fetch file path and download file from Drive to Device.

Answer (score 3):

@ Santosh Currently you are using Drive ID which will not be return Selected file name i am sharing my code below please use this class instead of PickFileWithOpenerActivity

```
   /**
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 * License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */



import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResource.MetadataResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityBuilder;

/**
 * An activity that pins a file to the device. Pinning allows a file's latest
 * version to be available locally all the time. Your users should be informed
 * about the extra bandwidth and storage requirements of pinning.
 */
public class PinFileActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE;

    private static final String TAG = "PinFileActivity";

    private DriveId mFileId;

    /**
     * Starts a file opener intent to pick a file.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);
        if (mFileId == null) {
            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setMimeType(
                            new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html",
                                    "application/pdf", "audio/mp3",
                                    "video/mp4", "text/plain",
                                    "application/msword", "image/jpeg",
                                    "image/png", "text/html" })
                    .build(getGoogleApiClient());
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER,
                        null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
            }
        } else {
            DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(),
                    mFileId);
            Log.i("File Name is ", "===========>>>>" + file);
            file.getMetadata(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(
                    metadataCallback);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles response from the file picker.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mFileId = (DriveId) data
                        .getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

            } else {
                finish();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the metadata response. If file is pinnable and not already
     * pinned, makes a request to pin the file.
     */
    final ResultCallback<MetadataResult> metadataCallback = new ResultCallback<MetadataResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Problem while trying to retrieve the file metadata");
                return;
            }
            if (result.getMetadata().isPinnable()) {
                showMessage("File is not pinnable");
                Log.i("==========All Info is here", "mIME tYPE=====>>>"
                        + result.getMetadata().getMimeType() + "======>"
                        + result.getMetadata().getTitle() + "====="

                        + result.getMetadata().getAlternateLink() + "======"

                        + result.getMetadata().getWebContentLink() + "======>>"
                        + result.getMetadata().getQuotaBytesUsed());
                return;
            }
            if (result.getMetadata().isPinned()) {
                showMessage("File is already pinned");
                return;
            }

            Log.i("==========All Info is here", "==========>>>");

            DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(),
                    mFileId);
            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setPinned(true).build();
            file.updateMetadata(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet)
                    .setResultCallback(pinningCallback);

        }
    };

    /**
     * Handles the pinning request's response.
     */
    final ResultCallback<MetadataResult> pinningCallback = new ResultCallback<MetadataResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Problem while trying to pin the file");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("File successfully pinned to the device");
        }
    };
}
```

I have put some Log in result call back which is display selected file and path

Thanks

Comment: All files open but some files cant be selected those have file type is Unknown pls help